# How to select laravel 6 option in edit ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

i want to edit user who lives in a country exactly in one state the country and state fields are two selects options fields and there is a relationship between them and user, and also state filled by select country, now i want to get the value of state in form edit, I tried the stack example but it didn't work.

**UsersController.php**

```
public function getStateList(Request $request)
    {
            $states = DB::table("states")
            ->where("country_id",$request->country_id)
            ->pluck("name","id");
            return response()->json($states);
    }
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
 $('#state').on('change',function(){
    var stateID = $(this).val(); 
    if(stateID){ 
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"{{url('get-city-list')}}?state_id="+stateID,
           success:function(res){               
            if(res){
                $("#city").empty();
                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                    $("#city").append('<option value="'+key+'" ${`{{$users->id}}` == "'+key+'" ? 'selected' : ''}>'+value+'</option>');
                });
            }else{
               $("#city").empty();
            }
           }
        });
    }else{
        $("#city").empty();
    }    
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to do the uglier way:

```
 $('#state').on('change',function(){
    var stateID = $(this).val(); 
    if(stateID){ 
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"{{url('get-city-list')}}?state_id="+stateID,
           success:function(res){               
            if(res){
                $("#city").empty();
                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                    if ({{$users->id}} == key) {
                       $("#city").append('<option value="'+key+'" selected>'+value+'</option>');
                    } else {
                       $("#city").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                    }
                    
                });
            }else{
               $("#city").empty();
            }
           }
        });
    }else{
        $("#city").empty();
    }    
   });
```